# Are hooks really subsumed by Slim Framework middleware?

Tags: php, event, middleware, hooks

I've been using the Slim Framework (v2) for a little while now to develop my user management system.

They recently released Slim 3, and according to the [upgrade guide](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html),

> Slim v3 no longer has the concept of hooks. Hooks were removed as they duplicate the functionality already present in middlewares. You should be able to easily convert your Hook code into Middleware code.

I'm not quite sure if I believe this.  Slim's [middleware](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html) allows you to modify the request before it hits your main application, or modify the response before it is sent out to the client.

However, this says nothing of modifying the behavior of the application itself, which hooks can do easily - the application simply anticipates points in the code where someone might want to modify the behavior, and call `applyHook` accordingly.

From what I can tell, the only way to modify the core behavior of an application via middleware is via exceptions - the middleware throws an exception, which the core application catches, and then does something else.  But this seems to me an abuse of the framework, and I have a hard time believing that this is what they mean.

Do hooks really "duplicate the functionality already present in middlewares"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my understanding of the word "hook" (and my usage of hooks in Slim 2), is different from that of the developers of Slim.  Apparently, the developers weren't even *aware* that people were using hooks to modify behavior at arbitrary points in the code - the assumption was that people were only using the `slim.before.*` and `slim.after.*` default hooks, which are indeed easily replaced with middleware.

*My* understanding of the word "hook" was something like that of [Wordpress hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#WordPress_Plugin_Hooks), which should really be called "event dispatchers".  In fact, this is what most real frameworks call them:

- [Symfony - EventDispatcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html)
- [Laravel - EventServiceProvider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events)
- [Zend - EventManager](https://zend-eventmanager.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

So the simple answer to this question is "no".

The more complicated answer is that Slim's hooks were never intended to be used as general-purpose event dispatchers.  They were meant to be used for the specific situations of injecting code before or after route handling.  Since middleware already handles this, Slim's hook feature was seen as redundant.

Of course, in real life, people do sometimes need to provide arbitrary points in their code (such as in the middle of a route) where people can inject additional code.  Slim v3 does not support this, because Slim is supposed to be a minimal, barebones framework.  Therefore, the current recommendation is to use a third-party event dispatcher, for example one of the components listed above, to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of hooks this is true. The way I understand hooks it that you can execute some code at a predefined point during the execution flow. Afterwards the application continues as if nothing happened. This is very abstract so I would like to express this using an example:

Lets say you can execute code when an `before_authentication` hook is encountered. Maybe you would like to initialize sessions before authentication and would therefore do this here. This can also be done through middleware.

Lets say you have a middleware component which handles authentication. Each middleware is defined inside an array and are executed in the defined order. You would then insert your `InitializeSessionMiddleware` component just before `AuthenticationMiddleware` is defined in the array.

Both of these solutions would work, but since Slim (AFAIK) is very HTTP focused, it would be more appropriate to write this as middleware.

Please keep in mind this is my understanding of midddleware and hooks. If you would like to modify how the application works at predefined points, I would look into exposing some callbacks, which has a predefined structure (interface?) unique for that specific point. This callback could be changed if the structure is correct.

I hope this can help you, happy coding.

Comment: So what you're saying is that my "hooks" would simply be "any point between two other middleware components"?

Comment: @alexw - They could be. But it would properly be more meaningful to keep closely related functionality in the same style with this being middleware. There are always room for interpretation though